# SQL Server Database Backup with Expire Date

Tags: sql-server, scheduled-tasks, database-backups

I have scheduled SQL db Backup. Full backup for every 2 days, Differential backup for every 1 day and transaction log backup for every 15 minutes.
and i have set distinct file name with timestamp(I guess file name should be same to overwrite)
if i want to use Expire date for backup. then how should i use for this schedule ?

Comment: What you mean with "Expire date"? You want remove the file? Bu the way are save the files in where type or hard drive?

Comment: Saving on local drive

Comment: Expire date is parameter to backup command.after that date we can overwrite existing file.

Comment: Saving on local drive.(hard disk) .expire date is parameter for BACKUP command .we can overwrite existing file after that date only

Comment: I think you can keep the schedule but you need to garante the file names will be the same

Comment: But i am confused in expireDate

Comment: Why excatly? The command, how to use or manage? Or you wannt help to create the script?

Comment: I know the command. but as per my scheduling. which expiredates are suitable? means full backup for every 2 days ,differential for every 1 day and tlog for every 15 minutes.In this case how should i use expireDate

Answer (score 0):

The `expiredate` parameter to the `backup` command determines whether SQL Server will allow you to overwrite that backup file or not.

I recommend not using it at all and rather creating a unique file name per backup (using a timestamp in the filename helps with this). You can then use another process to maintain your desired retention based solely on the filesystem metadata (i.e. the file's create date or similar).